# How to get the file/application name while downloading from the link in runtime using Java?

Tags: java

I want to get the name of the file while downloading from the URL. URL shows only partial name of the file, but I need exact name of the file at runtime. Suggest me the best possible way to get the exact file name in Java.

I am doing Automation testing and downloading a file is part of the requirement for different locales.

I want to get the file name while downloading and need to open the same programatically. I am working on Mac.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What methods are you calling? Please add more information to your question.

Comment: updated the question, pls suggest

Comment: Are you talking about the full path?